# using floating point arithmetic with Z3 C++ APIs

Tags: c++, floating-point, z3

I am trying to solve a problem of nonlinear real numbers using Z3. I need the Z3 to generate multiple solutions.
In the problem domain, precision is not a critical issue; I need just one or two decimal digits after the decimal point. so, I need to set Z3 not to explore all the search space of real numbers to minimize the time to find multiple solutions.

I am trying to replace the real numbers with floating point numbers. I read the fpa example in the c_api.c file but I found it a little bit confusing for me.

for example, let me assume that I want to convert the reals in the following code:

```
config cfg;
cfg.set("auto_config", true);
context con(cfg);

expr x = con.real_const("x");
expr y = con.real_const("y");

solver sol(con);
sol.add(x*y > 10);
std::cout << sol.check() << "\n";
std::cout << sol.get_model() << "\n";
```

}

I tried the following code  but it didn't work

```
config cfg;
cfg.set("auto_config", true);
context con(cfg);

expr sign = con.bv_const("sig", 1);
expr exp = con.bv_const("exp", 10);
expr sig = con.bv_const("sig", 10);


expr x = to_expr(con, Z3_mk_fpa_fp(con, sign, exp, sig));
expr y = to_expr(con, Z3_mk_fpa_fp(con, sign, exp, sig));

solver sol(con);
sol.add(x*y > 10);

std::cout << sol.check() << "\n";
```

and the output is:

```
Assertion failed: false, file c:\users\rehab\downloads\z3-master\z3-master\src\a
pi\c++\z3++.h, line 1199
```

My questions are:

1. Are there any detailed examples or code snippets about using fpa in C++ APIs? it is not clear to me how to convert the fpa example in the C API to C++ API.
2. What's wrong in the above code conversion?

Comment: Regarding the meaning of the assertion failure: `*` does not support floats, you need to use `Z3_mk_fpa_mul` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if using floats is the best way to go for your problem. But sounds like you tried all other options and non-linearity is getting in your way. Note that even if you model your problem with floats, floating-point arithmetic is quite tricky and solver may have hard time finding satisfying models. Furthermore, solutions maybe way far off from actual results due to numerical instability.

## Using C

Leaving all those aside, the correct way to code your query using the C api would be (assuming we use 32-bit single-precision floats):

```c
#include <z3.h>

int main(void) {
    Z3_config  cfg = Z3_mk_config();
    Z3_context ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
    Z3_solver  s   = Z3_mk_solver(ctx);

    Z3_solver_inc_ref(ctx, s);
    Z3_del_config(cfg);

    Z3_sort float_sort = Z3_mk_fpa_sort(ctx, 8, 24);

    Z3_symbol s_x = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "x");
    Z3_symbol s_y = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "y");
    Z3_ast      x = Z3_mk_const(ctx, s_x, float_sort);
    Z3_ast      y = Z3_mk_const(ctx, s_y, float_sort);

    Z3_symbol s_x_times_y = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "x_times_y");
    Z3_ast      x_times_y = Z3_mk_const(ctx, s_x_times_y, float_sort);

    Z3_ast c1 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, x_times_y, Z3_mk_fpa_mul(ctx, Z3_mk_fpa_rne(ctx), x, y));

    Z3_ast c2 = Z3_mk_fpa_gt(ctx, x_times_y, Z3_mk_fpa_numeral_float(ctx, 10, float_sort));

    Z3_solver_assert(ctx, s, c1);
    Z3_solver_assert(ctx, s, c2);

    Z3_lbool result = Z3_solver_check(ctx, s);

    switch(result) {
        case Z3_L_FALSE: printf("unsat\n");
                         break;
        case Z3_L_UNDEF: printf("undef\n");
                         break;
        case Z3_L_TRUE:  { Z3_model m = Z3_solver_get_model(ctx, s);
                           if(m) Z3_model_inc_ref(ctx, m);
                           printf("sat\n%s\n", Z3_model_to_string(ctx, m));
                           break;
                         }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When run, this prints:

```
sat
x_times_y -> (fp #b0 #xbe #b10110110110101010000010)
y -> (fp #b0 #xb5 #b00000000000000000000000)
x -> (fp #b0 #x88 #b10110110110101010000010)
```

These are single-precision floating point numbers; you can read about them in wikipedia for instance. In more conventional notation, they are:

```
x_times_y -> 1.5810592e19
y         -> 1.8014399e16
x         -> 877.6642
```

This is quite tricky to use, but what you have asked.

## Using Python

I'd heartily recommend using the Python API to at least see what the solver is capable of before investing into such complicated C code. Here's how it would look in Python:

```
from z3 import *

x = FP('x', FPSort(8, 24))
y = FP('y', FPSort(8, 24))

s = Solver()
s.add(x*y > 10);
s.check()
print s.model()
```

When run, this prints:

```
[y = 1.32167303562164306640625,
 x = 1.513233661651611328125*(2**121)]
```

Perhaps not what you expected, but it is a valid model indeed.

## Using Haskell

Just to give you a taste of simplicity, here's how the same problem can be expressed using the Haskell bindings (It's just a mere one liner!)

```
Prelude Data.SBV> sat $ \x y -> fpIsPoint x &&& fpIsPoint y &&& x * y .> (10::SFloat)
Satisfiable. Model:
  s0 = 5.1129496e28 :: Float
  s1 =  6.6554557e9 :: Float
```

## Summary

Note that Floating-point also has issues regarding `NaN`/`Infinity` values, so you might have to avoid those explicitly. (This is what the Haskell expression did by using the `isFPPoint` predicate. Coding it in Python or C would require more code, but is surely doable.)

It should be emphasized that literally any other binding to Z3 (Python, Haskell, Scala, what have you) will give you a better experience than what you'll get with C/C++/Java. (Even direct coding in SMTLib would be nicer.)

So, I heartily recommend using some higher-level interface (Python is a good one: It is easy to learn), and once you are confident with the model and how it works, you can then start coding the same in C if necessary.

Comment: It seems that it's time to try coding the problem using Python, looks much simple. I tried all possible workarounds to solve the nonlinearity issue but unfortunately it doesn't work. The last chance is to try using floating point. Thanks for your detailed answer.